# How can I place an EditText and TextView in a RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, customization, android-relativelayout

I have a RadioGroup inside of a RelativeLayout. I've got a few RadioButtons for different options, like "Bob", "Joe", and "Fred". However, I need to add an "Other..." option with an EditText right next to a RadioButton in case a user wants to enter "Steve". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just one idea that comes to mind is to use `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginTop` tags to position the `EditText` field where you need it to be. Be sure to use **dip** to support multiple densities across devices.

> ```
> <EditText
>     android:layout_marginLeft="65dip"
>     android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:text="" />
> ```

Then, if the user selects your **Other** radio button, just grab the value from `EditText`.